# Getting sum of diffrent totals using different dates

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table where I want to sum total amount for Different Dates, Bellow is my code

```
SELECT SUM( total_amount ) AS total FROM transaction WHERE execution_date BETWEEN  "2015-08-1" AND  "2015-08-31" AND execution_date BETWEEN  "2015-09-1" AND  "2015-09-30"
```

The code only returns Null. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `OR` instead `AND`.Since you want to display transactions that are in both range `2015-08-1" AND "2015-08-31` and `2015-09-1" AND "2015-09-30`,
Which is Contradiction, results `null`

```
SELECT SUM( total_amount ) AS total FROM transaction
 WHERE execution_date BETWEEN "2015-08-1" AND "2015-08-31" 
OR execution_date BETWEEN "2015-09-1" AND "2015-09-30"
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM( total_amount ) AS total FROM transaction
     WHERE execution_date BETWEEN "2015-08-1" AND "2015-09-30"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So that it help, others also